# JavaScript Regular Expression String Split

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

What I have is a string that I want to split.

I can set delimiters inside the string for example:

```
+++DELIMITER 1+++

text

+++DELIMITER R+++

text 2

+++NAME OF DELIMITER+++

text n

...
```

Edits after questions:

The string does not contain linefeed characters,
An example of string wourld be:

```
let string = "+++DELIMITER 1+++ text +++DELIMITER R+++ text 2 +++NAME OF DELIMITER+++ specialchars \"£$%%£$\"<>";

text n";
```

What i want to obtain is an array constructed like this:

```
resultarray=[
     ["DELIMITER 1", "text"],
     ["DELIMITER R", "text 2"],
     ["NAME OF DELIMITER", "text n"]
     ...
];
```

I think I have to use String.split method, but I don't know what kind o f regex to use.

Comment: Can you please share a sample input and any attempts? The input you have shared is not a string variable

Comment: does your string has some kind of linefeed?

Comment: Try `^\+{3}([^+]+).*\s+((?:(?!^\+{3}).*\s*)*)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/vuLOXg/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string and reduce single strings to pairs.

```js
var string = '+++DELIMITER 1+++text+++DELIMITER R+++text 2+++NAME OF DELIMITER+++text n',
    parts = string
        .split(/\+{3}/)
        .slice(1)
        .reduce((r, s, i) => r.concat([i % 2 ? r.pop().concat(s) : [s]]), []);
    
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: i think it's a problem with op and the lack of some code.